# AWS - T2 Instances for beta, low usage application

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an iOS application, which hits a backend we've set up on AWS.  Basically, we have a Staging and a Production environment, with some basic Load Balancing across two AZs (in Production), a small RDS instance, a small Cache instance, some SQS queues processing background tasks, and S3 serving up assets.

The app is in beta, so "Production" has a limited set of users.  Right now, it's about 100, but it could be double or so in the coming weeks.

My question is: we had been using t2.micro instances on Staging and for our initial beta users on Production, and they seemed to perform well.  As far as I can see, the CPU usage averages less than 10%, and the maximum seems to be about 25 - 30%.

Judging by these metrics, is there any reason not to continue using the t2 instances for the time being and is there anything i'm overlooking as far as how the credit system works, or is it possible that i'm getting "throttled" by the T2s?

For the time being, traffic will be pretty predictable, so there won't be 10K users tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to watch the CPU credits metric on the instances to make sure you dont get throttled. Set up alerts in CloudWatch for this and you should be fine.